# Text Classification into Predefined Labels, Unsupervised and Continuous learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to work on something, I want to classify customer calls into some n predefined categories. The frequency of words in my the calls cannot decide the labels. however, the category word will be present in the call.  And I do not have training data.

Also, I can classify the incoming text into labels, and i want my machine during the same time to learn from the new classified data.

eg: A Call comes - the system must be able to classify it into the n Categories and then i will label the call manually too, and then system should be able to adjust accordingly, weightage given to manual classification.

Answer (score 0):

You need train data or you can collect raw data and make classification manually(maybe using loops) after that use new data as your train data but this is not a good way.

Comment: thanks you for responding; the issue is i do not have the raw data or the data set :(

Comment: maybe this will help you https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-custom-classifier-build-your-own-text

Comment: thank you i had seen this, sounds almost what i need - however this is an online API :( I wanted to use something of my own, sorry for bothering you :) but thank you!